# Logic to obtain two even numbers from a set of sequentinal numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out a logic to obtain:

From a sequence of numbers $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \cdots$

Some function $f()$ which result in a new sequence $k = f(n) = k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4....
$
Where:
$IsEven(k)$ = false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, $\cdots$

Comment: Because it is a function I guess it could be a combination of operations? , and not limited to linear operations?

So I will say:
for $i$ in sequence $[n]$, define function $f(): \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, such that 

$f(i) =$
\begin{cases}
i+1 \mod 3, \forall i \equiv 0,1 \mod 3 \\
i \mod 3, \forall i \equiv 2 \mod 3
\end{cases}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}n\right)\right)$

For $n=0,1,2,3,...$

We get $f(n)=1,0,0,1,0,0,1,...$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).